# Multiple STL files on single web page using threeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl-format

Here I have one STL file that I am displaying with threeJS. I don't know how to render multiple STL Files in single web page. 
Here's my code:

```js
var container, camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.getElementById('pratik');
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 3, 0.5, 3 );
    scene.add( camera ); // required, because we are adding a light as a child of the camera

    // Controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    // lights
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    camera.add( light );

    // object

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load( 'files/wolf.stl', function ( geometry ) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533 } );

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        scene.add( mesh );

    } );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

}

function render() {

    var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

    camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 15;
    camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 15;

    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<div id="pratik"></div>
```

Now what if I need to include another file named 'mk6.stl', How will I do it?
Does anyone knows how to do it?
I have tried SketchFan, but its not made for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the code to load  a single STL file and insert it into your scene. The next step to load multiple files is straightforward, you would simply reuse your `STLLoader` instance. Basically you could do something like:

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load( 'FIRSTFILE.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );

loader.load( 'SECONDFILE.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

You could also use the loaders `load()` method in a loop if you have an array of URLs to load your STL-files from.